# Using IFMXCameraService.TakePhoto, is there a way of getting the image path?

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

Here is the code I am using.

```
procedure TForm1.getpic;
var
  Service: IFMXCameraService;
  Params: TParamsPhotoQuery;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXCameraService,
    Service) then
  begin
    Params.Editable := false;
    Params.NeedSaveToAlbum := True;
    Params.RequiredResolution := TSize.Create(640,640);
    Params.OnDidFinishTaking := DoDidFinishTakePic;
    Service.TakePhoto(nil, Params);
  end
  else
    xShowMessage('This device does not support the camera service');
end;

procedure TForm1.DoDidFinishTakePic(Image: TBitmap);
var
  Imagepath:string;
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
  Imagepath := fmx.platform.TMessageReceivedImagePath;
end;
```

Apparently from:

> http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/List_of_FireMonkey_Message_Types

there is TMessageReceivedImagePath found in fmx.platform.
However I cannot find it anywhere.  I am using 10.1 Berlin update 2. I posted this on the Embarcadero forum (thank you Remy for answer) but I am hoping someone has an answer here.

PS/ I would also like to store the DateTime of the picture captured.

In the mean time I have a workaround but it's ugly and I'm sure won't always work due to second-accuracy timing of the Take Photo.

```
procedure TForm1.DoDidFinishTakePic(Image: TBitmap);
var
  Imagepath:string;
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
  st := datetimetostr(System.SysUtils.Now,xfs);
  Imagepath := 'IMG_'+copy(st,1,4)+copy(st,6,2)+copy(st,9,2)+'_'+copy(st,12,2)+copy(st,15,2)+copy(st,18,2)+'.jpg';
end;
```

Comment: What's wrong with the answer I already gave you earlier? Subscribing to the `TMessageReceivedImagePath` message is the solution, so what is the actual problem you are having with it?

Comment: The problem is that TMessageReceivedImagePath cannot be found in any unit.  So yes all the code and solutions you provided will work, provided TMessageReceivedImagePath can be located.

Comment: You can use `FormatDateTime()` instead of chopping up the result of `DateTimeToStr()`: `ImagePath := FormatDateTime('"IMG_"yyyymmdd"_"hhnnss".jpg"', Now);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated on the [Embarcadero forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=171699), all you have to do is subscribe to the `TMessageReceivedImagePath` message, eg:

```
TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageReceivedImagePath, DoMessageListener);

...

procedure TForm1.DoMessageListener(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
var
  ImagePath: string;
begin
  if M is TMessageReceivedImagePath then
  begin
    ImagePath := TMessageReceivedImagePath(M).Value;
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Embarcadero documents the message is in the `FMX.Platform` unit.  If you can't find it there, check if it is in the `FMX.Platform.Android` unit (since it is an Android-specific message) or the `FMX.MediaLibrary` unit (which defines the other photo/video capture messages).

Comment: As stated in the forum, I cannot find TMessageReceivedImagePath in any unit.  Even using the "Find declaration" does not find anything.

Comment: OK you have declare both fmx.platform and fmx.platform.android in the uses clause and then it finds it. What a mission :(  I thought if you declare the parent that it should find all children components below?

Comment: @sandman `FMX.Platform.Android` is not a child of `FMX.Platform`. Units do not have parent/child relationships. And when looking for things, I prefer to use "Find in Files" in the $(BDS)\Source folder.